# What is the issue with this static variable assignment to a pointer in local function?

Tags: c++, c, static

```
int* func(int *ptr)
{
  static int a = 5;
  ptr = &a;
  return ptr;
}
```

Someone asked me this question in an interview. Now the point is, the variable 'a' is static, so, unlike ordinary variables which are declared, which loses it's value (popped from stack) once the function returns, this variable retains it's value as it is a static one.

Then i didn't understand, what's the issue with this piece of code?

Comment: Why do you say there's an issue?

Comment: What issue do you have with it?

Comment: I'm not convinced there is an issue. Who/what said there was?

Comment: I don't see any issue, but then why the question?

Comment: Well, technically, the question is "what's the issue?", not "is there an issue?"...

Comment: @kingsmasher1 I don't know. _You_ are asking the question!

Comment: Well, it the function parameter is completely useless. Other than that, I can see no issues.

Comment: Why Do **YOU** think there might be an issue with it?

Comment: @DanielDaranas: I am saying, i was unable to find any issue here, hence posting it. I also gave an explanation, in the question while asking it, that since it is static, so value is retained in data section, and not popped out. So asking you, do you see any issue in this?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 well then...   http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I see a couple of "issues": (1) It is not very readable: names of variables and the function itself say nothing to me. (2) It does not document its preconditions and postconditions, or what it does in any other way. In conclusion, I see this function as useless. I would never call such a function, because it means nothing to me.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 From my experience, being asked at an interview is not a guarantee that a question is good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no point in having `ptr` as a parameter. The passed value is not used. You could change this to

```
int* func()
{
  static int a = 5;
  return &a;
}
```

Comment: The OPs signature allows something like `int * b(NULL); if (func(b) && *b > 4) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: As opposed to `int* b; if ((b = func()) && *b > 4) { ...`?

Comment: @Pixelchemist I'm not sure what you mean, but `b` would still be `NULL` in your example, giving undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The value (address you're pointing to) of `ptr` that you are passing in is NOT changing outside the function as you are changing a locally scoped copy of `ptr`

It needs to be passed in by reference or pointer to pointer for it to change.

```
int* func(int **ptr)
{
  static int a = 5;
  *ptr = &a;
  return *ptr;
}
```

Comment: It's not an issue. And in OP's code, the `ptr` value is returned so the code also works, just no the same way. Btw the return statement is wrong in your code (and useless, no ?)

Comment: It is an issue as it isn't working the way he thinks it is. It is pointless as the above answer suggests, but it wasn't working the way it is in the OPs code.

Comment: You sure it shouldn't be `return *ptr`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue. `a` is static so it exists through the lifetime of the execution. It is syntactically invisible outside `func`. You are just returning the address of some "hidden" global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm bringing back your attention for local static variables. All time the variables will be remain same from last call. So, if you increase the variable `a=a+1` then next time the value is remain 6. Here come how it happens. Each local declare new space in memory in each call. But in static variable you are telling to use same memory for every time. So, pointer will remain same. That why you are getting same address. This is not unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an issue, unless the caller doesn't understand what the function does. This is quite possible, given that people may assume the function modifies the value pointed to by the parameter.

For instance, if somebody writes code like

```
int foo = 0;
func(&foo);
assert(foo == 5);
```

They will have an issue.

The interviewer may have been looking for a solution like:

```
int *func(int *ptr) {
    static int a = 5;
    *ptr = a; //modify value being pointed to by argument
    return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread-safety issue: returning a non-constant pointer to `a` makes it possible that some thread will modify the value while another thread is reading it. Data races have undefined behavior.

I'll also toss in that returning a raw pointer is horrible practice, since I haven't seen it in the other answers. `int& func()` should be preferred.